# Why is sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder so slow?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why is the one-hot encoder provided by sklearn so slow?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')
categories = np.expand_dims(np.array(list(map(chr, np.arange(97,123)))), axis=1)
enc.fit(categories)
vec = np.expand_dims(list(map(chr, np.random.randint(97,123,1000))), axis=1)
%timeit enc.transform(np.array([['b']]))
%timeit (categories == 'b')[:,0] *1
```

output:

```
569 µs ± 3.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
3.23 µs ± 58.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

100x slower than the naive way of doing this, while it actually could be faster by using the knowledge that elements of `categories` are unique.

Comment: I'd guess this method is too general. Your approach is probably more specific to the problem and, thus, is faster, because the more general method has to take into account more possible cases, making it slower. Also, a solution to the general case is often more difficult than the one to a subset of this general case, so `OneHotEncoder` may be solving a problem harder than you actually need.

Comment: The code sample does not work if I copy-paste to the python interpreter: `import numpy as np` is missing. Which python are you using? Which version of sklearn?

Comment: Transform takes a list of samples. You are testing with one sample, so constant-time overheads might dominate. Try to test again with 1000 samples or more, which is more typical for a dataset. Also you should probably leave the construction of the numpy array outside of the test

Comment: @jonnor, good point but no.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone stumbles here -- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/116582/why-does-scikit-learns-onehotencoder-take-so-long-on-a-large-dataset answers it and recommends switching over to pandas.get_dummies, which is much faster